# react server side return null and just do browser rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

See the code below,I use **SSR** in project, but some components just can render in browser-end since it use `window` or `document` object.So I do a switch, in server side: return null,and in browser-end return the real component. But I got a checksum error. What should I do?

```
render() {
        if (!process.env.BROWSER) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            const OwlCarousel = require('react-owl-carousel').default;
            return <OwlCarousel
                    className="owl-theme"
                    loop margin={10} nav
                >
                    <div className="item" style={{backgroundColor:'#3EA5E9'}}><h4>1</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
                    <div className="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
                </OwlCarousel>;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can render null on both first render, and then on componentDidMount which will only be run on client do a change state to force rerender

Comment: That is a good idea, I will have try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example component

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = { render: false }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (process.env.BROWSER) this.setState({ render: true })
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.render && <ComponentToRender />
  }
}
```